Splitting a list of numbers into two groups with its best combination possible without splitting a number
I want to split a list of quantities between two groups of peoples without splitting any single quantity.
The goal is to split the quantities into two groups using the  best combinations possible.
Please find below an example:
List of quantities:
The quantities are in different rows as below.



ID
Quantities




1
30


2
36


3
5


4
23


5
1


6
4


7
1



I want to find the way to split these quantities into two halves (Between Group A and B) where the sum of quantities in each group can be exactly equal or can be some less than other group.
In the above mentioned example, I can split the quantities as

Group A: 30,36 = 66 ; Group B: 23,5,4,1,1 = 34
(or)

Group A: 30,23 = 53 ; Group B: 36,5,4,1,1 = 47


Among the above two possible ways, 2nd combination is the best. Like wise I want to find the possible combinations and pick the best of all.
Can someone please help me with the logic to solve the above mentioned math using a SQL query?
Thanks in advance.

Looks like the Bin Packing Problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem . It's at least NP-hard, so don't hold your hopes high for an ideal solution. Check the link, maybe you'll find some algorithmic ideas suitable for SQL. Oh, and you may be also interested in a similar Knapsack Problem.

This sounds closer to the Multiway number partitioning problem, with k = 2.

So, what do you think of the answer provided?

I highly recommend to do not use pure SQL for such tasks. That's very complex logic and would be far better implemented in your application. Keep in mind SQL's purpose is mainly to fetch data and if necessary do some trivial logic like sorting, grouping or summing data, that's all.
Anyway, if you urgently want to use SQL only, you need following steps to get the expected outcome:

Build all combinations of quantities in your table
Create a comma separated list of them
Get the half amount of all quantities in your table (for your sample data, that's 50)
Fetch the list of quantities whose total amount is closest to above "half total amount" of all quantities, this will be Group A
Remove this list of quantities from the entire list of quantities, the rest will be Group B
Return both groups

Following query attempts to execute exactly those steps and to return the intended result:
WITH cte ( combination, curr ) AS (
  SELECT CAST( y.quantities AS VARCHAR(100) ),
         y.quantities
  FROM   yourtable y
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CAST( c.combination + ',' + CAST( y.quantities AS VARCHAR(2) ) AS VARCHAR(100) ),
         y.quantities
  FROM   yourtable y
         INNER JOIN
         cte c
         ON ( c.curr < y.quantities )
),
sub AS 
  (SELECT combination,
     SUM(DISTINCT CAST(value AS INT)) AS total
     FROM cte 
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(combination, ',')
     GROUP BY combination),
outcome AS 
  (SELECT * FROM
  (
    (
      SELECT TOP 1 'Group A' AS [Group], combination FROM sub
      ORDER BY ABS( (SELECT SUM(quantities) * 0.5 FROM yourtable) - total)
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
      SELECT 'Group B', STRING_AGG(quantities, ',') 
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY quantities) FROM yourtable
    )
  ) t)
SELECT * FROM outcome WHERE [Group] = 'Group A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  [Group], 
  REPLACE(combination, 
    (SELECT combination FROM outcome WHERE [Group] = 'Group A') + ',', '') 
FROM outcome
WHERE [Group] = 'Group B';

At least for your sample data, the query succeeds and produces this result:



Group
combination




Group A
23,30


Group B
1,1,4,5,36



See this sample fiddle
As said, the whole idea is risky and I guess it might fail in some cases. For example, if the table has lot of rows or the list of numbers in one combination gets very long, the amount of different combinations or different numbers could exceed some limitations of CTE's or the STRING_AGG function.
I think, as already mentioned, there is no really safe query which can't run in such trouble, so better just fetch the data of this table and do this logic in your application using Linq or similar tools.

Thats Impressive!
